# How to change NSServices which in info.plist and make changes happen in system?

Tags: macos, service, info.plist

I add service in info.plist like

```
<key>NSServices</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>NSMessage</key>
        <string>service</string>
        <key>NSPortName</key>
        <string>ServiceDemo</string>
        <key>NSMenuItem</key>
        <dict>
            <key>default</key>
            <string>Service Demo</string>
        </dict>
        <key>NSRestricted</key>
        <false/>
        <key>NSRequiredContext</key>
        <dict/>
        <key>NSSendTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>NSStringPboardType</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

Run the app, everything is right.
 Now, i want to change some values, but after i edited in info.plist -> run -> type command in Terminal

```
/System/Library/CoreServices/pbs -dump_pboard
```

Nothing changed.
I tried clean DerivedData -> relaunch Xcode -> shift+command+K -> run, nothing changed.
Restart computer is not help.
I want to know how the services in info.plist be installed at first launch? and how to make changes happen when i run the app?

By the way, these codes are in AppDelegate.swift

```
func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
    NSApplication.shared.servicesProvider = ServiceProvider()
    NSUpdateDynamicServices()
}
```

see [demo on GitHub](https://github.com/ibirdbluer/ServiceDemoForStackOverflow) for detail

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried running `/System/Library/CoreServices/pbs -update` after building the app in XCode?